# Multiselect dropdown listbox code using cakephp

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cakephp

i have two dependent select box in my form for selecting country and state.

when i select country India then it should populate its dependent state.upto this my code working fine...

bit i want to make this multiselect listbox.

Ex - if i select two countries from county dropdown then it populates states from two countries....not of single selected country.

below is my code...

**HTML Select list box code**

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('service_area_category_id', array(
    'id' => 'shipping_type',
    'required' => false,
    'multiple' => 'multiple',
    'type' => 'select',                                           
    'class' => 'form-control drop-arrow',
    'label' => false,
    'options' => $serviceCategory,
    'empty' => '--Select--'
));
?>

<?php
echo $this->Form->input('ship_category', array(
    'class' => 'form-control drop-arrow',
    'required' => false,
    'id' => 'state',
    'label' => false,
    'options' => '$states',
    'empty' => '--Select--'
));
?>
```

**Controller function**

```
public function getServiceArea(){     
    $this->loadModel('ServiceAreaCategory');        
    $serviceCategory = $this->ServiceAreaCategory->find('list', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'is_active' => 1
        ),
        'fields' => array(
            'ServiceAreaCategory.id',
            'ServiceAreaCategory.name'
        ),
        'order' => 'name ASC'
    ));
    $this->set('serviceCategory', $serviceCategory);     
}


public function loadSkills() {
    $this->loadModel('Skill');
    $states = array();
    if (isset($this->request['data']['id'])) {
        $states = $this->Skill->find('list', array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Skill.id',
                'Skill.skill_name'
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Skill.service_area_category_id' => $this->request['data']['id']
            )
        ));
    }            
    echo json_encode($states);
    exit();
}
```

**Ajax Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#shipping_type").on('change', function() {
            var id = $(this).val();           
            if (id) {
                var dataString = 'id=' + id;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "Profiles", "action" => "loadSkills")); ?>',
                    data: dataString,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('.spinicon').show();
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $('.spinicon').hide();
                    },
                   success: function(html) {
                        $("#loding1").hide();
                        $.each(html, function(key, value) {
                            $('<option>').val('').text('select');
                            $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($("#state"));
                        });
                        $('#state').selectpicker('refresh');
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: When posting code, please format it in a properly readable manner - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your cakephp side function should be

```
public function loadSkills() {

        $exploded_ids=explode(",",$this->request['data']['country_ids']);
        $ids= "IN ('".implode(",",$exploded_ids).")";
        $this->loadModel('Skill');
        $states = array();
        if (isset($this->request['data']['id'])) {
        $states = $this->Skill->find('list', array('fields' => array('Skill.id','Skill.skill_name'),'conditions' => array(
        'Skill.service_area_category_id '.$ids )));
        }            
        echo json_encode($states);
        exit();
}
```

And your Javascript and AJAX code Should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#shipping_type").on('change', function() {
            var ids = $(this).val();           
            if (id) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "Profiles", "action" => "loadSkills"),true); ?>',
                    data: {country_ids: ids}
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('.spinicon').show();
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $('.spinicon').hide();
                    },
                   success: function(html) {
                        $("#loding1").hide();
                        $("#state").html("");
                        $.each(html, function(key, value) {
                            $('<option>').val('').text('select');
                            $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($("#state"));
                        });
                        $('#state').selectpicker('refresh');
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have edited url in to pass full url instead of relative usl. please check

Comment: please check pr($this->request['data']['country_ids']); die(); variable $this->request['data']['country_ids'] should be array type.

Comment: I have edited my code for esplode comma saprated string into array. I assumed ajax pass array instead of comma saperated string. please check now.

Comment: I have edited please check it... and try your self in loadSkills() method

Comment: but now when i select multiple values it shows below error.. <strong>SQL Query: </strong>
  SELECT `Skill`.`id`, `Skill`.`skill_name` FROM `db_Errand`.`skills` AS `Skill`   WHERE `Skill`.`service_area_category_id` IN (&#039;1&#039;,&#039;3) </p>
<p class="notice">

Comment: its okay...and thanks for your help...if i got solution than i can also accept your answer....

Comment: you have to use some tricks on IN condition when $ids counter greater then 1

Comment: I have changed its last time from my side ... sorry

Comment: okay..again this is not worked for me...but for your response and answers i am going to accept your answer.....